# Building a product page with product-info below the image. Flex or not?

Tags: html, css

I'm practicing html and css by trying to build a product page. Even though I am following an example, I am confused by the flex example.

Example: https://css-tricks.com/designing-a-product-page-layout-with-flexbox/

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/rhtb8q3k/

I want the product info to be below the product image, exactly how they have it in the jackets image. `product-card` is a container that has both the image and the product info. They have:

```
.product-card {
  padding: 2%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 16%;
  display: flex;
}
```

But when I have `display: flex;`, the product info is beside the picture. If I remove it, the text shows below the image. What's the difference between my code and the example? I don't see `text-align` or `flex-direction` either.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, not only on external sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to do this with `flex`. You're only missing the `flex-direction` property.

The available options are: `row` and `column`. `Row` will have one thing next to the other, in a row - so things go from left to right. `Column` will display things stacked, from top to bottom. There are also reverse variations: `row-reverse`, and `column-reverse`, which do what you would expect them to from the name.

The default value for this property (when you don't specify it in your code) is `row`, so that's why your product image shows up left to the product data.

So, if you add

```
flex-direction: column;
```

to your `.product-card`, the product data will appear below the product image.

As a side note, changing this property will change the main axis and cross axis of the flex element, which means that `justify-content` and `align-items` will behave differently. You did not specifically ask about this, but you may want to read up on that next: https://codeburst.io/understanding-basic-concepts-of-css-flexbox-ffa657dc39c1.

Comment: Oh, that was easy. Visually, it seems there is no difference between not adding ```display: flex;``` and adding ```display: flex;``` with ```flex-direction: column;```. Is it wrong to do it one way or another and will it affect other parts of my code going forward?

Comment: Flex provides you with some specific features that might come in handy, like alignment and size calculations . If you don't plan to use them, you don't need to use this setting, but you should definitely look into them. Knowing how to use flex will really take your CSS skills up a level.